# Como verificar datos repetidos dentro de una array vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

obtengo los datos de un DB, esta columna almacena los datos divididos por **";"** por lo cual realizo un split, obviamente esto me genera un vector que puede variar de numero de elementos  entre cada registro, cada vez que leo un registro debo crear y analizar un nuevo vector para eliminar los valores repetidos.

Ej.

`vectTg = reader(1).ToString.Split(";")`

output
 `(12, 12, 12, 1, 4, 78, 6,90, 90, 12, 13)`

Al final debo manejar solamente los elementos que sean diferentes dentro de este vector, los repetidos seran ignorados.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, decide cambiar el enfoque del problema y en vez de tratar de analizar un array, lo converti en una lista che simplemente usando el siguiente codigo resolvio el problema.

```
 Dim tgList As New List(Of String)
 tgList.AddRange(variableArray)
 Dim noTgDuplicados As IEnumerable = tgList.Distinct 'Esta instruccion hace todo el trabajo
 For Each noDuplicado in noTgDuplicados
    --Lo que vas a hacer con el contenido de la lista
 next
```